# データベースをソーティングしましたが、ウエッブページに影響しません？

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

このコマンドでデータをソーティングしました。

```
 SELECT * FROM `estates`  
 ORDER BY `estates`.`price`  ASC
```

データベースできちんとソーティングができました。
なんですがウエッブぺジーに影響しませんでした。
ララベルを使ってMVCでデータを表示しています。
これはウエッブページの中身です。何を間違っていますが教えていただけませんか？
ありがとうございます。

```
<table cellspacing='0'> <!-- cellspacing='0' is important, must stay -->
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th width="150px">会社名</th>
          <th width="150px">物件名</th>
          <th width="250px">住所</th>
          <th width="150px">販売価格</th>
          <th width="100px">総戸数</th>
          <th width="150px">専有面積</th>
          <th width="100px">間取り</th>
          <th width="100px">バルコニー面積</th>
          <th width="100px">竣工時期</th>
          <th width="100px">入居時期</th>
        </tr>
      <thead>
      <tbody>
       @foreach($estates as $estate)
        <tr class="even">
          <td>{{$estate->company_name}}</td>
        <td><a href="{{json_decode($estate->link)}}" target="_blank">{{$estate->name}}</a><br/></td>
          <td>{{$estate->address}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->price}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->hows_old}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->extend}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->rooms}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->balcon_m2}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->old}}</td>
          <td>{{$estate->entery}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

問題を解決しました。

コントローラーにあるコードこれから

```
$estates = Estates::get();
```

これに変更しました。

```
$estates = Estates::orderBy('price')->get();
```